# PowerShell nested loop for renaming files in directory

Tags: loops, powershell, directory

I am trying to do a nested loop in PowerShell.  I am renaming images in a several sub directories but i need the loop to reset based on it finding a new directory.

Here is the code I wrote but I can't get it to work as it gives me an error saying the file doesn't exist.

```js
function rename-cruise {
    
    Param([string]$parkname, [string]$extension=".jpg")
    
    if(!$parkname){
        $park = $args[0];
    } else {
        $park = $parkname;
    }

    $dirs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer };

    foreach($dir in $dirs){
        if($dir -cnotlike "177"){

           

            $i = 0;
            $currentDir = get-location;
            $location = "$currentDir\$dir";

             write-host $currentDir
             write-host $location

             Get-ChildItem -Path $location -Filter "*$extension" |
             ForEach-Object {

               if($i -lt 10){

                    $newName = "$park-0$i$extension";
                    Rename-Item $_.Name -NewName $newName;
            
               } else {

                    $newName = "$park-$i$extension";
                    Rename-Item $_.Name -NewName $newName;

               }

               $i++;
       
            }

        }
    }
    

}
```